# How to assign function argument to a variable name in R [example in the details]?

Tags: r, function

I have a function defined as follows:

```
my_fun <- function(x, y = "abc") {
y.default.value = 8
}
```

How can I dynamically make a y.default.value to be abc.default.value or for y = "gre" gre.default.value?

I am dealing with y names that I want to implement into variable names, please advice how should I do this?

Comment: It's weird to store important information in variable names in R. Sounds like it would be better to have a list of `default.values(abc=1, gre=2)` and then you can do `default.values[[y]]` to get the right one out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do what you are asking for...

```
my_fun <- function(x, y = "abc") {
                assign(paste0(y, ".default.value"), 8, envir=.GlobalEnv)
                }
```

You can omit the `envir=.GlobalEnv` if you only want the new variable to exist within the function call.

I'm not sure what `x` is for though!

Comment: What the envir = .GlobalEnv for? I need it in the function only.

Comment: In that case you don't need it.

Comment: Thanks a lot is there any other alternative to this task? I need to convert string I get from paste/paste0 functions to a column name which is variable:
df$column_name_created_from_paste_function

Comment: You can do that with `df[,name_var] <- ` where `name_var` is a variable.  You can't then use the `df$colname` format though - you have to use `df[,colname]`